# One-Way ANOVA experiment ideas

Tags: anova

I need to conduct an experiment and use one-way ANOVA test to analyze the data. I know what the test is, but I am having difficulty figuring out an experiment to perform. Any suggestions on an experiment? Something simple I can do at home.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: measure yourself each morning, noon and evening, for the next 20 days or so. Then see if the weights tend to differ for the 3 measuring times.

If you don't have so much time, just ask 20 friends to do this on any one day and send you the results. As a funky exercise: figure out the differences in these two designs and what the consequences are :)

Use imdb or something alike to find the top 20 comedies, action movies and chickflicks, and check whether the duration of the movies tends to differ.

Make 4 nice drawings. Now go out on the street and have 100 people rate each of them (funky exercise 2: does it matter whether or not the same people judge all 4 drawings?).

Take three pots (of different formats). Put 0.1l of water in each and put them on the stove. Time how long it takes until the water boils (you'll have to define how you measure this). Repeat until you have enough measurements to find out whether one pot boils 0.1l of water faster than the others.

The possibilities are endless: just make sure you have groups and some numerical quantity you can compare between them.

Comment: `go out on the street` violates the OP's assumption `Something... I can do at home`